# .obj model shows up different in various programs?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, .obj

I want to make a random terrain generator that can export .obj files. So first I tried making one(manual). This is the test file:

```
# testOBJ.obj
0 deff
v 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 0.000000
v 0.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000

f 1 2 3
f 2 3 4
f 5 6 7
f 6 7 8
```

These are 2 planes above each other. If I drop that into Visual Studio 2015, it shows the model as I expect. But if I drop it in a model viewer like open3mod, it shows only 3 triangles instead of 4. If I load the model in Unity, it shows only 2 triangles. What am I doing wrong?

The ["Utah tea pot"](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs148-10-summer/as3/code/as3/teapot.obj) model looks right in all 3 programs. Mine does not. I cannot see why.

I need this terrain for most likely games, and I use Unity for that. So it would be nice if it would work with Unity.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at **Primitive Topologies** in *open3mod* in the *visual studio* program and in *unity* as they might be using different primitive topologies. For example, if you use **Triangle Strip topology** in your program, then **with 4 vertices you can render 2 triangles**. And if you use **Triangle List topology**, then you **need to define at least 6 vertices to render 2 triangles**.

Answer (score 1):

Unity does not display just 2 triangles. It displays all four of them. Just rotate your view to the "bottom" and you'll see the other two.

The problem you have encountered is due to polygon winding. That is, if you look at the triangle from a certain direction, its indices are numbered in a clockwise or counter-clockwise order. Generally, polygons which are facing you will have a clockwise winding order.

When establishing a normal for you triangle, the order in which you use the vertices in the calculation influences the direction of your normal and thereby the direction your triangle is facing.

In a closed mesh, triangles with a normal pointing away from the viewer/camera are usually hidden by the rest of the mesh. They are "back facing" and you don't really need to draw them. This optimization of the rendering process is called [back-face culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling).

Some renderers don't use this optimization, and in some, you may be able to turn it off. Unity does however use it by default.

The solution is to take good care to ensure that your polygon winding is consistent for your surface. A minor fix of your file to the following, when loaded in Unity, will give you an appropriate result:

```
# testOBJ.obj
0 deff
v 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 0.000000
v 0.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000

f 1 3 2
f 2 3 4
f 5 7 6
f 6 7 8
```

Comment: Thanks, this test model does work now. You swapped the 2e and 3e vertex for every uneven face. Does work for every model? Or are there other rules and does it look like this rule because there not enough faces/vertices?

Comment: As said, you have to make certain the winding is the same for all triangles. Clockwise in this case. That's the one rule. It's not about swapping indices for "uneven faces".